# How to deliberately lock a MySQL row such that even SELECT will return an error?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

I'm trying to use MySQL row locking to basically emulate a MuteEx on a row. Lets say that my table has 2 columns, an id and a text field, and three entries (1,a) (2,b) and (3,c).
SELECT * FROM table; would return these results.
I can lock a specific row the normal way.

```
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = '2' FOR UPDATE;
```

However, if from a second connection I were to SELECT * from table. It would return all 3 results. Is there a way for row level locking to basically prevent any SELECT from seeing/using a row that is locked? Basically I'm trying to prevent anyone from using the row that is currently being used/manipulated, or even viewing the row as its data (since it's being used/manipulated) can't be trusted to be accurate at the time of a SELECT.

Comment: Possibly not what you (or I) want to hear, but it appears that if the second selector also uses `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, it will wait until the initial lock is released.

Answer (score 6):

If you set the transaction isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE`, `InnoDB` wil implicity append `LOCK IN SHARE MODE` to all `SELECT` statements.

This mode conflicts with the locks placed by `SELECT FOR UPDATE` and the `SELECT`s will lock.

Note, though, that `InnoDB` may lock more rows than satisfy the `WHERE` condition. This is because it locks all rows *scanned*, not only those *matched*.

Say, you have an index on `col1` and this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   col1 = 1
        AND col2 = 2
FOR UPDATE
```

uses this index.

This will lock *all* records with `col1 = 1`, even those with `col2 <> 2`

Answer (score 5):

You need a `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`. Using it with SELECT guarantees no one else is locking any rows with `FOR UPDATE`.

e.g.

Client A does `SELECT * FROM table WHERE type=2 FOR UPDATE`

Client B does `SELECT * FROM table LOCK IN SHARE MODE` and hangs here

Client A writes/INSERTs/UPDATEs something then does a `COMMIT`

Client B now un-freezes and resumes processing

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the row data *can* be trusted even while you are manipulating it.

If you start a transaction from one connection, other connections will not see any of your changes until you commit the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a native, locking specific mechanism to do that, but my first instict would be to give the table a status column (e.g. `locked`) and setting that to `1` when locking the row. A `select` sensitive of this would then always add a `WHERE locked != '1'` condition to any query.

On a side note, I don't know what you are doing, but isn't this a task that should be done a level or two above the database engine?

Comment: I was just curious as to whether or not this was possible from the database. As my current method felt a bit clunky. The project is multithreaded, and each thread needs to select work from a database (work is added from several different areas constantly), however, no two threads should be attempting the same work at the same time, so my current solution was a muteex on a function that selected available work, and then updated those rows specifically to say that they are being worked before releasing the mutex. I guess I'm already doing the best solution.